# Covering java and scala source in integration test

Tags: java, scala, sonarqube, jacoco, scoverage

I have a question, but after check in google I´m afraid with hard solution.

I´m using Jacoco with a jacoco agent to cover the code of the libraries that I run in my integration test  using jacoco agents.

Everything was fine for now, creating the reports and covering the code. But then the problem starts once that I start adding new modules written in Scala. Then I realize that the reports were created but in Sonar the code show up as not covered.

I checked scoverage https://github.com/scoverage/scoverage-maven-plugin but not sure how this it´s gonna work in my use case with integration test and covering sources in a jar file that I run.

Any ideas suggestions?

Comment: So your question is `How to show coverage on scala code?`, right?

Comment: yes, how to make it in a multi-module propject with scala and java